# Polygon and line intersecting with intersectLinePolygon not behaving properly

Tags: java, math, vector, libgdx, collision

I'm trying to detect a collision between a small rectangle around the cursor and a "Connector", which is basically just a line between two points.

Now, I've decided to use the Intersector.intersectLinePolygon(p1, p2, polygon) method to do so, but when I run the code. It detects a collision everytime any of the rectangle X or Y points are in the same range as the line's bounding box and I can't really get my head around it. The desired result is the collision reporting only when the rectangle is actually touching the line.

```
        Vector3 worldPos = cam.unproject(new Vector3(mouseX, mouseY, 0));

        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(worldPos.x-4, worldPos.y-4, 8, 8);

        Boolean connectorIntersected = false;   
        for (int i = 0; i < nodeConnectorHandler.getAllConnectors().size(); i++) {
            //Getting two points that make the connector line
            Node n1 = nodeConnectorHandler.getAllConnectors().get(i).getFrom();
            Node n2 = nodeConnectorHandler.getAllConnectors().get(i).getTo();

            float x1 = n1.getCX();
            float y1 = n1.getCY();
            float x2 = n2.getCX();
            float y2 = n2.getCY();

            //Making a polygon out of rect
            Polygon p = new Polygon(new float[] {
                    rect.getX(),
                    rect.getY(),
                    (rect.getX()+8f),
                    rect.getY(),                                                                                                            
                    (rect.getX()+8f),
                    (rect.getY()+8f),
                    rect.getX(),
                    (rect.getY()+8f)
            });

            //Checking if the line intersects the polygon (representing the rectangle around the cursor)

            if (Intersector.intersectLinePolygon(new Vector2(x1,y1), new Vector2(x2,y2), p)) 
            {   
                selectedIndex =  nodeConnectorHandler.getAllConnectors().get(i).getID();
                System.out.println("ConnectorIntersected!");
                connectorIntersected = true;
            }                   
            break
         }
```

The code reports a collision everytime the rectangle is in these areas (shown in yellow, aprox):

[photoshopped image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5sPLZ.png)

The red line inbetween those 2 dots is the "connector"
Cursor is right below the line. It reports a collision in those yellow areas spanning across the whole game world.

I suppose I'm either not using the function properly or that I've made some obvious mistake. Or is this how the function should react? I really don't know. Thanks for any help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, apparently I used the wrong method. intersectSegmentPolygon works as expected. My bad ¯_(ツ)_/¯.